# onChange does not trigger FilteringSelect

Tags: javascript, html, onchange, dojo

I am not able to find out how I can work around this issue. This is the jsfiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/3w4D3/2/

Now in the jsfiddle, I can change the selection in `FilteringSelect` and as you can see, with the alert, that `onChange` event is triggered. But under a particular scenario the `onChange` event is not triggered.

Following is the repro steps,

(Make sure that you have California selected in the `FilteringSelect` and execute the entire repro step without clicking anywhere else)

1. Type in the `FilteringSelect` an invalid entry (any garbage)
2. You will see that the button is disabled
3. Now select the entire garbage value and type `ca` for California
4. You can see `California` in the result.
5. Click on it. This click does not trigger the `onChange` event

The issue is that if an invalid entry is typed into the `FilteringSelect` and then entirely deleted and the same previous selected value is typed in and reselected from the result, the `onChange` event is not triggered.Due to this I am not able to enable the disabled button.

Any solution to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Solved it. Removed the `onKeyUp` and used `watch()`

http://jsfiddle.net/3w4D3/3/